# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} [(1/n)^2+({2}/{n})^2+ \cdots +({3n}/{n})^2]$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \Bigg[\Bigg(\frac{1}{n}\Bigg)^2+\Bigg(\frac{2}{n}\Bigg)^2+ \cdots +\Bigg(\frac{3n}{n}\Bigg)^2\Bigg]$$

Express this sum as an integral. I know $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x) = x^2$.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{3n}\frac{1}{n} \Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big)^2$$ The $3n$ is tripping me up. I know $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n} \Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big)^2 = \int_{0}^{1}x^2 dx$$ 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @mickep: Thanks, it must be

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{3n}}\frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2 = \int_{0}^{\color{red}{3}}x^2 dx$$

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: Hint (as an alternative to the very sound approach in @RRL's answer): you know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\frac{1}{\color{red}{3}n} \Big(\frac{k}{\color{red}{3}n}\Big)^2\to\int_{0}^{1}x^2 dx$$  hence $$\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\frac{1}{n} \Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big)^2\to\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Break the sum into three parts.

Here is the second part:

$$\frac1{n} \sum_{k= n+1}^{2n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2= \frac1{n} \sum_{k= 1}^{n}\left(\frac{n+k}{n}\right)^2=\frac1{n} \sum_{k= 1}^{n}\left(1 + \frac{k}{n}\right)^2\\ \to\int_0^1(1+x)^2\,dx = \int_1^2x^2 \, dx$$

Answer (score -3):

Hint: What is $\frac{3n}{n}$?

Everything else looks good.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain themselves? That the last term in the sum is $3^2$ is a very strong hint to the nature of the upper end point of the integration interval.